# How to get lat long from dragable route by google map api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, routes, latitude-longitude, direction

Is it possible during dragable routing we can get latitude and longitude value along the routing way

If it have please leave me a link or solution

Thank for help

Comment: What do you mean by "during dragable routing"?  Do you mean dynamically while the route is being dragged?  Or after the user has finished dragging it?

Comment: I mean the user has finished dragging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the dragend event.
2. Add a listener to the route
3. when the dragend event fires get the points out of the route.

[Example of how to iterate through the coordinates in a dragged route](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-draggable2Xml.html) (look at the getPolylineXml function)

Answer (score 0):

See my example to get LatLng for all points in route

```
directionsRenderer.addListener("directions_changed", function() {             
  var lat = [];
  var lng = [];
  result = directionsRenderer.getDirections()               
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) 
  {
    //console.log(myroute.legs[i].start_location.lat())
    lat[i] = myroute.legs[i].start_location.lat();
    lng[i] = myroute.legs[i].start_location.lng();
  }

    i=myroute.legs.length-1;
    lat[i+1] = myroute.legs[i].end_location.lat();
    lng[i+1] = myroute.legs[i].end_location.lng();

    console.log(lat)
    console.log(lng)                                
});
```